# JavaFX Script for server side applications

Tags: java, javafx, server-side, javafx-1

Has anybody tried to use *JavaFX Script* in server side applications?

The language itself looks quite nice and modern, and is fully Java compatible. If Sun is serious about it, it could be quite ubiquitus on the server side too, where Java is strong.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right , but the main focus for JavaFx is RIA and many organizations are thinking to opt this technology for themselves .